# Fortran Operators

Tags: generics, fortran, operator-keyword

I am implementing the cross product of two vectors using ^, however 
I am getting an error.Not aware how the problem can be resolved.

Here is the code

```
Interface Operator (^)
    Module Procedure vector_cross_product
End Interface Operator (^)

Contains

Function vector_cross_product (u, v) Result (w)

    !!$ Input
    Type (Vector), Intent(in) :: u, v

    !!$ Output
    Type (Vector) :: w

    w% x = (u% y * v% z) - (u% z * v% y)
    w% y = (u% z * v% x) - (u% x * v% z)
    w% z = (u% x * v% y) - (u% y * v% x)

End Function vector_cross_product
```

This is the corresponding errer I am getting using gfortran

```
Interface Operator (^)
                    1
Error: Syntax error in generic specification at (1)
lib/vectors.f:110.18:

  Module Procedure vector_cross_product
                  1
Error: MODULE PROCEDURE at (1) must be in a generic module interface
lib/vectors.f:111.3:

End Interface Operator (^)
   1
Error: Expecting END MODULE statement at (1)
```

Comment: There are reasons for these restrictions. They are not going away with Fortran 2015 and I cannot really see them going away before the fixed source form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the standard rules out the use of arbitrary symbols, such as `^`, when defining operators.  In the draft of the 2008 standard I have to hand para 7.1.6.1.4 states

> A binary defined operation is an operation that has the form x1
>   defined-binary-op x2 or x1 intrinsic-operator x2 and that is defined
>   by a function and a generic interface.

A defined-binary-op is a sequence of letters between stops, for example `.cross.` or `.times.`, and an intrinsic-operator is one of the operators defined in the language standard (`+`, `<`, `*`, etc).

Prodded by @francescalus, I should add that the sequence should be no longer than 63 letters and should not be the same as any of the intrinsic operators (e.g. `.eq`) or logical literals (e.g. `.true.`)

Comment: [That sequence defined by R723 in 7.1.2.8.]